# How can I adjust the HTML font size?

Tags: html, css

[image: big]

Based on the image above, I've faced some problem when I tried to add this code `display:block`, but nothing has changed. What is the problem with my text? 
 How can I fix them?
I'm using this reset codes:
http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/ 
 And I just set font-size:80px;

```
 .counter-box p
{
    font-size: 20px;
}

.counter-box .counter
{
    font-size: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set font-size: 40px; for example?

Comment: Please post the code you're working with.

Comment: added some codes

Comment: I forced to use margin I want my texts with display:block

Comment: @KnightM check out my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use line height property:

```
.counter-box .counter
{
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height:80px;
}
```